# java.text.ParseException when trying to parse string date do lucene

Tags: java, date, parsing

I'm trying to index a date field with lucene 4.10.3. So, first I convert the string to SimpleDateFormat in Java using:

```
//Date sample 1-APR-1987 11:09:07.45
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SS");
```

It goes fine, but, when I try to parse  1-APR-1987 11:09:07.45 it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1-APR-1987 00:02:13.34"
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: What is your current `Locale`? And are you _absolutely_ sure you want `DD-MMM-YYYY` and not `dd-MMM-yyyy`?

Comment: Add date as 01-APR-1987 00:02:13.34

Comment: `DD` means "day in year", i.e. April 1st would be something like 90 or 91. That in combination with a month doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Nor does `YYYY`, which means "week year" rather than "year".

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I have to use Locale.US so that it works!